# Select an element by a class that multiple elements share with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select an element with the class 'submenu-expand', and add another class to it.

```
$('.menu-item').on('click',function(){
$('.submenu-expand').toggleClass('expanded')
})
```

This code works, but the problem is that multiple elements share that class, so jQuery selects all of them. I tried to do it this way since '.submenu-expand'is inside of 'menu-item':

```
$('.menu-item').on('click',function(){
$('this>.submenu-expand').toggleClass('expanded')
})
```

HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-940" class="menu-item">
<a href="" >אודות</a>
<button class="submenu-expand" tabindex="-1"></button>
</li>
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: What's the HTML structure?

Comment: Without your html we can only guess, but maybe you need something like this: `$(this).find('.submenu-expand')`

Comment: To get the child of a clicked element, use `$(this).find(selector)` where `selector` is the selector you want to find. Here, the selector you want is `.submenu-expand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```js
$('.menu-item').on('click', '.submenu-expand', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded')
})
```

```css
.expanded {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-940" class="menu-item">
    <a href="">אודות</a>
    <button class="submenu-expand" tabindex="-1">Click</button>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-940" class="menu-item">
    <a href="">אודות</a>
    <button class="submenu-expand" tabindex="-1">Click</button>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-940" class="menu-item">
    <a href="">אודות</a>
    <button class="submenu-expand" tabindex="-1">Click</button>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-940" class="menu-item">
    <a href="">אודות</a>
    <button class="submenu-expand" tabindex="-1">Click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```